# a nuclear $C^*$-subalgebra in $\prod_n M_n(\Bbb C)$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Does there exist a non-unital nuclear $C^*$ algebra $A$ of $\prod_nM_n(\Bbb C)$ such that $A$ properly contains $\oplus_n M_n(\Bbb C)$ and each element $(x_n)\not \in \oplus_n M_n(\Bbb C)$ we have $\lim_ntr_n(x_n)=0$,where $tr$ is the unique tracial state on $M_n(\Bbb C)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, let $A = (\bigoplus M_n ) + \mathbb{C}\cdot P$ where $P$ is a projection of the form $P = (p_n)$ with each $p_n \in M_n$ a rank 1 projection. This is a one-dimensional extension of $\bigoplus M_n$, and so it is nuclear. (If $I$ and $A/I$ are nuclear then so is $A$.)