# construct a nuclear $C^*$ algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Can we construct a non-unital nuclear $C^*$ algebra  $A$ such that    $I=\bigoplus_n M_n(\Bbb C)$ is an essential proper ideal in $A$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The subalgebra of $\prod M_n$ given by elements $(x_n)_n$ such that $$\lim_n x_{2 n} \in \mathbb{C} 1$$ and $$\lim_n x_{2 n + 1} = 0$$ is nonunital and contains $I$ as an ideal. To see that it is essential just check that if $(x_n)_n$ is annihilated by every finitely supported sequence it has to be $0$. It is a finite extension of $I$, therefore nuclear.

Comment: This is pretty similar to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318875/a-nuclear-c-subalgebra-in-prod-n-m-n-bbb-c) I gave yesterday.